# Get summed CPU usage via Prometheus API

Tags: curl, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I have a prometheus query like below. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVQtt.png)
`(100 * avg by (instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode!="idle"}[1m])))`

**It give a sumarized CPU usage of an instance via the GUI**

> You have access to a prometheus demo instance [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=(100%20*%20avg%20by%20(instance)%20(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total%7Bmode!%3D%22idle%22%7D%5B1m%5D)))%0A&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=1&g0.range_input=1h)

**And I want to have the same result via the prometheus API**
`curl 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=MYQUERY`

---

I tried & searched...
`curl -g 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=node_cpu_seconds_total'`

Give me the CPU usage for all CPU individually...

`curl -g 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=(100 * avg by (instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode!="idle"}[1m])))'`

Give me `400 Bad Request`

Can someone give me a clue or help me to transform my request?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
curl -g 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=(100*avg%20by%20(instance)(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode!=\"idle\"}[1m])))'
```